# Is it possible to open a page that contain external javascript and css in a div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

/* I need to open a webpage in a div that webpage contain included javascript and css. is it possible to load that javascript and css with with that page or i need to include that files in parent page?

Eg :-

```
**Page1.php**
```

*/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<a href="#" onclick="check();">click me</a>
<div id="success"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<script>

function check(){
$('#b').load('test.php #target');
}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

//  I need to open test.php in div

// **test.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id='target'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 I am from test page. <a href="#" onClick="loaddata()">Click Here</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

//  In test.php script.js included

//  **script.js**

```
function loaddata()
{
    alert("hii");
}
```

//  My problem is while doing like this script.js is not working

Comment: That's what an `<iframe>` is for.

Comment: try using include or require function in php ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your page1.php file should look like below.  You just use include('myPhpPageName.php'); inside of your php tags and that will include whatever myPhpPageName.php would be.  Check out test.php below to see what is needed on that page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <b>Successful Response (should be blank):</b>
<a href="#" onclick="check();">click me</a>
<div id="success"></div>
<div id="b"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<div id='target'>
 I am from test page. <a href="#" onClick="loaddata()">Click Here</a>
</div>
```